# any PHP or Ruby library to convert Tranditional Chinese to Simplified Chinese or vice versa?

Tags: iconv, big5

Is there any PHP or Ruby library to convert Tranditional Chinese to Simplified Chinese or vice versa (Big5  <--> GB)?  The iconv library won't do it, as it merely converts the encoding, but the glyph stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some leverage with 1.9

> > Encoding.constants.grep /gb/i
> >     => [:GB18030, :GBK, :GB1988, :GB12345]
> >
> > Encoding.constants.grep /big5/i
> >     => [:Big5, :BIG5, :Big5_HKSCS, :BIG5_HKSCS, :Big5_UAO, :BIG5_UAO]

so it's something like

[How can I convert a string from windows-1252 to utf-8 in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951891/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8-in-ruby)

original = File.open('name', 'r:original_encoding').read

original.force_encoding('new_encoding')

Though I've never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this class for PHP - http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3130.html