# Ruby HTML Entity Problem

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, html-entities, windows-console

New to Ruby and am wondering how to get the following to print just the degree symbol...

```
require 'htmlentities'
coder = HTMLEntities.new
puts coder.decode('&deg;')
```

Currently the command line (Windows) output is: Â°

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `HTMLEntities.decode` returns a string in UTF-8, and your console is choking on that encoding.  You'll have to re-encode your string before passing it to `puts`.

If you're using Ruby 1.9.2, it looks like the code is fairly straightforward (based on the [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001113) and [Encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Encoding.html) documentation):

```
puts coder.decode('&deg;').encode(Encoding.find('<Whatever-Windows-Uses>'))
```

You might have to try a couple different encodings before you find something your console can understand.

If you're on an older version of Ruby, it looks like the re-encoding is doable through [Iconv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951891/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8-in-ruby) - I suspect you're just going in the opposite direction).

Hope this helps!