# Ruby: Remove invisible characters after converting string to UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, whitespace, windows-1252

I am working with text coming from [this website](http://www.eximsystems.com/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm#sal002) with `windows-1252` charset. Converting the text to UTF-8 was done using `force_encoding`, but the text still contains whitespace that I can't get rid of. The whitespace cannot be removed using `text.gsub!(/\s/, ' ')` or a similar technique.

The [iconv](https://rubygems.org/gems/iconv) gem doesn't do the trick either - as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951891/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8-in-ruby). It is clear that the whitespace is a remnant of the original text and the `windows-1252` charset as I get a `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` warning if I don't specify the encoding as UTF-8.

I'm not an expert of text encoding so I may be overlooking something trivial.

**Update**: This is the script that I currently use.

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://www.eximsystems.com/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm'
html = Nokogiri.HTML(open(URL))

# Extract Paragraphs
text = ''
html.css('p').each do |p|
  text += p.text
end

# Clean Up Text
text.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')

puts text
```

This is a sample of the text that contains invisible characters that I try to remove. The space before the number **16** is what I am referring to.

> cobraron aliento para conversar con él.   16 Al punto corrió la voz, y
>   se divulgó generalmente esta noticia en el palacio del rey: Han

Comment: Can you paste the whitespace character you're trying to remove?

Comment: @ProGNOMmers I have updated the question with the Ruby script and a sample of the text including the invisible whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to know exactly what's going on for you.  I'll point out, however, that [String#force_encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) doesn't transcode the String; it's a way of saying, "No, really, this is UTF-8", for example.  To transcode from one encoding to another, use [String#encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-encode).

This seems to work for me:

```
require 'net/http'
s = Net::HTTP.get('www.eximsystems.com', '/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm')
s.force_encoding('windows-1252')
s.encode!('utf-8')
```

In general, `/[[:space:]]/` should capture more kinds of whitespace that `/\s/` (which is equivalent to `/[ \t\r\n\f]/`), but it doesn't appear to be necessary in this case.  I can't find any abnormal whitespace in `s` at this point.  If you're still having problems, you'll need to post your code and a more precise description of the issue.

**Update:** Thanks for updating your question with your code and an example of the problem.  It looks like the issue is non-breaking spaces.  I think it's simplest to get rid of them at the source:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://www.eximsystems.com/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm'
s = open(URL).read            # Separate these three lines to convert &nbsp;
s.gsub!('&nbsp;', ' ')        #  to normal ' ' in source rather than after
html = Nokogiri.HTML(s)       #  conversion to unicode non-breaking space

# Extract Paragraphs
text = ''
html.css('p').each do |p|
  text += p.text
end

# Clean Up Text
text.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')

puts text
```

There's now just a single, normal space between the period at the end of 15 and the number 16:

> 15) Besó también José a todos sus hermanos, orando sobre cada uno de ellos; después de cuyas demostraciones cobraron aliento para conversar con él. 16 Al punto corrió la voz, y se divulgó generalmente esta noticia en el palacio del rey: Han venido los hermanos de José; y holgóse de ello Faraón y toda su corte.

Comment: I have updated the question with the Ruby script. I have also tried your approach, but I don't get the result that you are seeing, that is, the resulting text still contains invisible characters/whitespace.

Comment: @BartJacobs Thanks for updating your question.  I've updated my answer.  With your update it became clear that it wasn't an encoding issue at all; it was `&nbsp;` in HTML becoming non-breaking space in your text.

Comment: Fantastic. For future reference, how did you discover non-breaking spaces were the culprit?

Comment: @BartJacobs It was just a hunch, I guess. Using my `net/http` code, I didn't have the extra spaces, but using `open-uri` and Nokogiri, I saw the same thing you did.  So I suspected perhaps there where `&nbsp;`s in there that Nokogiri was converting, and looking at the raw string, this was clearly the case.

Comment: Thank you very much on the tip about using `/[[:space:]]/`. I thought it was just an alias, but it clearly removes some whitespace that `/\s+/` or `strip` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use text.strip for removing the whitespaces.

Comment: [String#strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) only removes leading and trailing whitespace.  And I'm not sure, but I suspect it wouldn't be much better at catching unusual whitespace than `/\s/`.